# Cloud hosting for small hospital?

Tags: asp.net, heroku, cloud, web-hosting

I created a hospital management app for small hospital. They wanted cloud solution, I would have used Amazon Web Service or Heroku , since I am most familiar with them.

This is the project detail.

1: The project has 4 MySQL database (separated from department and purpose)

2: I designed it using asp.net core Web API as backend

3: Front end uses Vue Js

4: Used docker and Gitlab ci/cd pipeline to deploy to test environment (Heroku free)

5: Max 50 users will access this system simultaneously.

6: website main operation is getting data and inserting data to database and some task scheduling for reminder.

Ok now my problem hospital management wanted economical, secure and responsive hosting provider. 
Also needed database back up too.

While I would like to use AWS , it doesn't seems to be economical.

So what other options I have?

Comment: This type of question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please familiarize yourself with what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: You can consider asphostportal.com. They fully support asp.net core. I also host my site with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use godaddy / hostgator or other hosting providers which resale cloud hosting. AWS is not that much costly either if you are using it effectively. you require windows VM with MySQL database? I have worked with AWS and Azure. Azure seems to be good option too but for that need to know exact hardware requirement and scaling.

Comment: Website only needs to read and inserting data not much about any kind of processing. What are the details I should look for, what about the other costs like domain name, ssl , ?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/products/one-click-apps/ I doubt it works with Windows OS. you have any software dependency document with you for deploying your product?

Comment: I can use docker. And also asp.net core can be used in Linux

Comment: any 4GB linux VM should work then I guess. for data backup you can write crone job to backup and email the data or save to external drive / source.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion gave me the idea on what I should  look for

Comment: I am glad I could help you